# photoeditorsdk apply filter to a UIImage for IOS with swift

Tags: ios, swift, photoeditorsdk

I have gone through the Android API document of photoeditorsdk and found that I can directly apply a filter on an image using

```
ImageFilter imageFilter = new ColorFilterAD1920();
imageFilter.renderImage(Bitmap bitmap, boolean previewRendering)
```

doing this returns me with an image with the desired filter applied.

How can i achieve the same in IOS

Comment: This may help you : https://github.com/skdevil/SimpleFilterOps

Comment: hi @SharadChauhan thanks for the comment, but i am trying to integrate filters provided by photoeditor sdk https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/